# Sublime Text 3 Project

Tags: reference, sublimetext3, auto-update, rainmeter

I am trying to use sublime for editing and making rainmeter skins, I have installed a plugin that recognizes rainmeter code nice.

In my code I have an @include=\somelocation...

at that location the file has things like colour=something

In the actual file being loaded fontColor=#colour#

How do I get it so that if I change the name of colour inside the location file it would update everywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`Find in Files...`** functionality, located in the **`Find`** menu. In the `Find:` box, enter what you'd like to look for (the buttons to the left allow you to search by regex, respect capitalization, and other options - just mouse over for a description). In the `Where:` box, enter where you'd like to search. If nothing is entered, the search will run in all open files and folders. Click on the  <kbd>...</kbd>  button for some extra options. Finally, enter what you'd like to replace the found values with (if anything, you can also use this dialog to simply search files).

Clicking <kbd>Find</kbd> will first perform the search for you, so you can verify its results. Clicking <kbd>Replace</kbd> will do all the replacements.